# session_lock issue on codeigniter 4

Tags: php, ajax, session, memcached, codeigniter-4

I have configured session store as memcached, it was working fine in PHP 7.1 with codeIgniter 2,

After upgrading PHP 7.1 to 8.2 and codeIgniter 2 to 4
I am getting an error on multiple async ajax call

```
session_start(): Unable to clear session lock record
in SYSTEMPATH/Session/Session.php on line 928.
 1 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->errorHandler()
 2 SYSTEMPATH/Session/Session.php(928): session_start()
 3 SYSTEMPATH/Session/Session.php(250): CodeIgniter\Session\Session->startSession()
 4 SYSTEMPATH/Config/Services.php(674): CodeIgniter\Session\Session->start()
 5 SYSTEMPATH/Config/BaseService.php(252): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session()
 6 SYSTEMPATH/Config/BaseService.php(193): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic()
 7 SYSTEMPATH/Config/Services.php(641): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::getSharedInstance()
 8 SYSTEMPATH/Config/BaseService.php(252): CodeIgniter\Config\Services::session()
 9 SYSTEMPATH/Common.php(988): CodeIgniter\Config\BaseService::__callStatic()
```

codeIgniter official website also suggests to use `session_write_close()` for resolving this issue. But this did not work for ajax concurrent call.

Comment: There are a huge of number of changes between 2 and 4.

Comment: How did you upgrade from CI v2 to v4?

Comment: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/399

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I am rewriting the code in CI4 because of no any shortcut way to upgrade CI 2 to 4